# \listoffigures does not display the caption of the figures

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, labels

I am currently writing my thesis and need to create a list of figures (and tables, but have not reached that point yet). I have successfully created the actual list, but it does not display the caption or label of the figures. Additionally, there are no spaces in the listings.
It looks like this (see attached picture):

[image: What it looks like now]

And I would like it to be displayed in this format:

Figure number, the actual caption that I wrote OR the label I chose, Page number.
Ex: Fig 2.2, System Boundaries LCA, 18

**The code used for the list of figures**:

```
 % List of figures (add to table of contents)
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename} 
\listoffigures
```

**This is the code I have used to insert my figures:** (in case I have made an error here and that is why it does not work.)

```
\begin{figure} [H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth] {figure/Images/System boundariesLCA.JPG}
    \caption{Life cycle stages for a building according to the standard SS-EN 15978 \citeyear{StandardLCA2011} }
    \label{fig:System Boundaries LCA}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: some code you have not shown has broken latex's  caption handling, it will be hard to help unless you show an example. Start from a copy of your document and delete everything not related to showing a list of two figures. then add that to your question

Comment: Also if you have added or removed hyperref or another package that changes the syntax of aux files, delete the aux and lof files and run latex twice more. If you get an error, show the error message not the pdf output in your question.

Comment: Additionally are you by any change ignoring compilation errors? for example in overleaf? Additionally you really shouldn't be using `[H]` for figures unless you like holes in your PDFs.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, they solved the issue.